# Identity with binomial coefficients and k^k

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergeometric-functions, combinatorial-identities

In process of doing some computations on Hilbert schemes, I stumbled across the following identity, for $k \ge 2$:
$$
k^{k-3} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{k-2}{i-1} i^{i-2} (k-i)^{k-i-2} 
$$
which can be verified computationally for small values of $k$ (I did it for the first 500).

This is actually a special case of a bigger problem, so I'm hoping to get ideas about what methods might be applicable to prove this kind of identity.

I understand that there are good methods for automatically proving hypergeometric identities, but am I correct in thinking that this is not hypergeometric, due to the $k^{k-3}$ type terms?

**EDIT**
Here is a link to the bigger question that I had that this is a special case of: [Counting some binary trees with lots of extra stucture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272820)

Comment: My impression is that (1) this should follow from one of the "Abel identities" in Table 1.2 in §1.5 of Riordan's "Combinatorial identities" book, and (2) there may be a proof using trees.

Comment: Let me multiply your identity by $2$ and substitute $n$ and $k$ for your $k-2$ and $i-1$. Then, your identity becomes $2\left(n+2\right)^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k} \left(k+1\right)^{k-1} \left(n-k+1\right)^{n-k-1}$. The right hand side counts all forests having exactly two connected components on a given $n+2$-element vertex set, but it counts them twice because it enforces an order on the components. The $\left(n+2\right)^{n-1}$ on the left hand side, meanwhile, counts all trees on this vertex set. So why does the equality hold? ...

Comment: ... Okay, I don't know, but I could bet that a bijective proof is known. But if you don't insist on a bijective proof, it is a particular case of the "Abel identity" with $p = -1$, $q = -1$, $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ in Table 1.2 of §1.5 of John Riordan, *Combinatorial Identities*, 1979.

Comment: @darijgrinberg If trees are rooted, you get forests by removing the root, and trees from forests by rooting them together. Does this make sense?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: This way I don't have control over the number of connected components; or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, the identity $2\left(n+2\right)^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k} \left(k+1\right)^{k-1} \left(n-k+1\right)^{n-k-1}$ is the particular case for $x = 1$, $y = n+1$, $z = -1$ of the identity (2) in [Victor J. W. Guo, *Bijective proofs of Gould-Mohanty's and Raney-Mohanty's identities*, arXiv:1005.4258v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4258v1). So, yes, there is at least one bijective proof. Probably an understatement.

Comment: Hm you are right, sorry. Maybe then cut the tree at an edge?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I thought so, but there are $n+1$ edges, unlike the $n+2$ factor I want to kill. And I don't see a multijection at work here.

Comment: But $k$ starts with $0$, does not it mean you also have forests with one of the components empty? It would give you "cuts" with the whole tree on one side and the empty tree on the other...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: No. Such forests would correspond to $k=-1$ or $k=n+1$, both of which are outside of the range. But now that you brought this up, I see that **my interpretation in terms of forests was wrong** because $\dbinom{n}{k}$ is not the number of ways to choose $k+1$ from the $n+2$ vertices (that would be $\dbinom{n+2}{k+1}$). No wonder I found no multijection then... There is probably still an interpretation using forests, but it should be less obvious (maybe something like what I said, but with two vertices fixed).

Comment: Ah! The right hand side is the number of forests on the vertex set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\right\}$ having precisely two connected components, with one component containing $1$ and the other component containing $2$. This is precisely the number of trees on the vertex set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\right\}$ containing the edge $\left\{1,2\right\}$ (because removing/adding this edge gives a bijection between these forests and trees). How to count these trees? The number of all trees on the vertex set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\right\}$ is $\left(n+2\right)^n$ (by ...

Comment: ... Cayley's formula), and the probability for such a tree to contain the edge $\left\{1,2\right\}$ is $\dfrac{n+1}{\left(n+2\right)\left(n+1\right)/2}$ (because each such tree has $n+1$ edges, and each edge is contained in the same number of trees by symmetry reasons). Thus, the number of all trees on the vertex set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\right\}$ containing the edge $\left\{1,2\right\}$ is $\dfrac{n+1}{\left(n+2\right)\left(n+1\right)/2} \cdot \left(n+2\right)^n = 2 \left(n+2\right)^{n-1}$, which is our left hand side. QED!

Comment: Indeed this is a special case of Abel's identity, see answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/255333/1532 for the question on important formulas in combinatorics. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214927/important-formulas-in-combinatorics

Comment: @j.c.: Done! (It ended up much longer, because the Guo paper I cited in my comments above gets the identity wrong and I don't really see how they prove it anyway... also, because my bijective proofs always end up long for some reason.)

Comment: It is possible to prove Abel identities automatically. See, e.g., Shalosh B. Ekhad and John E. Majewicz,
A short WZ-style proof of Abel's identity,
The Foata Festschrift, 
Electron. J. Combin. 3 (1996), no. 2, Research Paper 16, http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i2r16

Comment: I've just realized that this question has already been discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186151/bijective-proof-of-an-abel-hurwitz-type-identity .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's denote $T(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}x^n}{n!}$ the exponential generating function of labeled rooted trees, and $U(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-2}x^n}{n!}$ the corresponding function for unrooted trees. We will use the fact that $xU'=T$ and $xe^T=T$, both of which can be derived algebraically or combinatorially. Your identity follows from the relation
$$2\left(T(x)-U(x)\right)=T^2$$
since the coefficient of $x^{k}$ on the left is $\frac{2k^{k-3}}{(k-2)!}$ and the corresponding coefficient on the right is $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{i^{i-1}}{i!}\cdot\frac{(k-i)^{k-i-1}}{(k-i)!}$.

To get a quick proof of this notice that both sides only have terms of order $x^2$ or higher. Therefore it is enough to prove the derivative of this relation
$$2T'-2U'=2TT'$$
$$\iff xT'-xU'=xTT'\iff xT'(1-T)=T\iff T'(1-T)=e^T$$
$$\iff 1=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{T}{e^T}\right).$$

---

I hope it's clear from above that in principle all such identities follow from the basic relation $xe^T=T$ and all its derivatives. I know it's usually common to give references to books or surveys, but I really like the video lectures by Zagier available [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9kd4mpdvWcBOyZJgYQ1CMtgyz_RcwP3c), under the title "Partitions, Modular Forms, and Moduli Spaces" (these are based on a forthcoming paper by Dubrovin, Zagier and Yang). In a series of talks he presents how quasimodular forms appear in enumerative geometry. However in the first couple of lectures he focuses on what he calls "Lambert space" (nonstandard terminology from what I can tell, coming from the closely related [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)) which is essentially the space of series that are linear combinations of $T$ and its derivatives. He shows, for example, how generating functions of maps or Hurwitz numbers belong to this Lambert space.

Comment: Great! I'll see if this can also solve my more general problem. Can you clarify what you mean by "all such identities"?

Comment: @Drew, For example $$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}i^{i-2}(k-i)^{k-i-3}=k^{k-5}\frac{5k^3+21k^2+94k-120}{12}.$$ Proving such an identity amounts to expressing both sides as coefficients of some differential polynomial expression in $T$, and then showing that the corresponding differential relation can be derived from $xe^T=T$.

Answer (score 13):

Here are two proofs of your identity, which I have hinted at in my comments.

### The identity

Let me first restate your identity with the letter $k$ renamed as $n$:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n\geq2$ be an integer. Then,
>   $$
> n^{n-3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-2}{i-1}i^{i-2}\left(
> n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}.
> $$

### First proof: the Abel identity and its friends

The first proof of Theorem 1 will actually show a more general identity:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. In the polynomial ring
>   $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y,z\right]  $, we have
>   $$
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(
> n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}=\left(  x+y\right)  \left(  x+y-nz\right)
> ^{n-1}.
> $$

Note that both sides of the equality in Theorem 2 are well-defined polynomials
in $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y,z\right]  $ (not just rational functions in
$\mathbb{Q}\left(  x,y,z\right)  $): Indeed,

- the only denominators that appear on the left hand side arise from the
  $\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}$ term for $k=0$ and from the $\left(  y-\left(
  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}$ term for $k=n$; but both of them are cancelled
  by the $xy$ factor appearing in each addend.
- the only denominator that appears on the right hand side arises from the
  $\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n-1}$ term for $n=0$; but this denominator is
  cancelled by the $x+y$ factor.

Theorem 2 is a well-known fact in umbral calculus: It says that the sequence
of the Abel polynomials (the sequence $\left(  p_{0},p_{1},p_{2}
,\ldots\right)  $ whose $n$-th term is $p_{n}=x\left(  x-nz\right)  ^{n-1}$,
where $x$ is considered an indeterminate and $z$ a constant) is of binomial
type (i.e., it satisfies $p_{n}\left(  x+y\right)  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom
{n}{k}p_{k}\left(  x\right)  p_{n-k}\left(  y\right)  $). As such, it is
probably proven all across the literature. I also think that Theorem 2 is what
the equation (2) in [Victor J. W. Guo, *Bijective proofs of Gould-Mohanty's
and Raney-Mohanty's identities*,
arXiv:1005.4258v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4258v1) is supposed to be (I say
"supposed" because equation (2) as it appears in Guo's preprint is false).

Let me derive Theorem 2 from an even better known identity, namely the *Abel
identity* (appearing as equation (1) in [the above-cited paper by Victor J. W.
Guo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4258v1)):

> **Theorem 3.**  Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. In the polynomial ring
>   $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y,z\right]  $, we have
>   $$
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y+kz\right)
> ^{n-k}=\left(  x+y\right)  ^{n}.
> $$

As before, both sides of the equality in Theorem 3 are well-defined
polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y,z\right]  $.

The most well-known particular case of Theorem 3 is probably the one obtained
by substituting $-1$ for $z$:

> **Theorem 4.** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. In the polynomial ring
>   $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y\right]  $, we have
>   $$
> \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(  x+k\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-k\right)
> ^{n-k}=\left(  x+y\right)  ^{n}.
> $$

Theorem 4 appears in many places, e.g. (with a boring proof) in my [solution
to Problem 4 on the 6th QEDMO 2009](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/QEDMO6P4long.pdf) (scroll down to Theorem 4). Yes, I am that lazy at
reference hunting. $\square$

I am going to reverse the cart and derive Theorem 1 back from Theorem 4. The
first step is getting Theorem 3:

*Proof of Theorem 3.* Work in the field $\mathbb{Q}\left(  x,y,z\right)  $ of
rational functions in $x,y,z$. Substitute $\dfrac{x}{z}$ and $\dfrac{y}{z}$
for $x$ and $y$ in Theorem 4. The result is
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\dfrac{x}{z}\left(  \dfrac{x}{z}-k\right)
^{k-1}\left(  \dfrac{y}{z}+k\right)  ^{n-k}=\left(  \dfrac{x}{z}+\dfrac{y}
{z}\right)  ^{n}.
$$
Multiplying this equality by $z^{n}$ and clearing denominators results in
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y+kz\right)
^{n-k}=\left(  x+y\right)  ^{n}.
$$
Thus, Theorem 3 is proven. $\square$

Next, I shall derive Theorem 2 from Theorem 3:

*Proof of Theorem 2.* Substituting $y-nz$ for $y$ in Theorem 3 yields
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-nz+kz\right)
^{n-k}=\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}.
$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}  & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(
x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  \underbrace{y-nz+kz}_{=y-\left(  n-k\right)
z}\right)  ^{n-k}\nonumber\\
\tag{1}
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(
n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k}.
\label{pf.t2.1}
\end{align}
Multiplying this equality by $y$, we find
\begin{align}
y\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}  & =y\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x\left(
x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k}\nonumber\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\underbrace{\left(
y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k}}_{=\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)
z\right)  \left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(
n-k\right)  z\right)  \left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}
\nonumber\\
\tag{2}
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  \dbinom{n}
{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
^{n-k-1}.
\label{pf.t2.2}
\end{align}

On the other hand, substituting $y$ and $x$ for $x$ and $y$ in \eqref{pf.t2.1},
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\left(  y+x-nz\right)  ^{n}  & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}y\left(
y-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  x-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{n-k}y\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
^{n-k-1}\left(  x-\left(  n-\left(  n-k\right)  \right)  z\right)  ^{n-\left(
n-k\right)  }
\end{align*}
(here, we have substituted $n-k$ for $k$ in the sum). Since $y+x=x+y$, this
rewrites as
\begin{align*}
& \left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\dbinom{n}{n-k}}_{=\dbinom{n}{k}}y\left(
y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\underbrace{\left(  x-\left(
n-\left(  n-k\right)  \right)  z\right)  ^{n-\left(  n-k\right)  }
}_{\substack{=\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k}\\=\left(  x-kz\right)  \left(
x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}}}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}y\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
^{n-k-1}\left(  x-kz\right)  \left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}y\left(  x-kz\right)  \left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying this equality by $x$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
x\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}  & =x\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}y\left(
x-kz\right)  \left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)
z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  \left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  x-kz\right)  \dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}.
\end{align*}
Adding this equality to \eqref{pf.t2.2}, we find
\begin{align*}
& y\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}+x\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  \dbinom{n}
{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
^{n-k-1}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  x-kz\right)  \dbinom{n}
{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
^{n-k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\left(  \left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)
+\left(  x-kz\right)  \right)  }_{=x+y-nz}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(  x+y-nz\right)  \dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\\
& =\left(  x+y-nz\right)  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
& \left(  x+y-nz\right)  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)
^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(  n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}\\
& =y\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}+x\left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}=\left(
y+x\right)  \left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}\\
& =\left(  x+y\right)  \left(  x+y-nz\right)  ^{n}.
\end{align*}
Dividing this equality by $x+y-nz$, we obtain
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  y-\left(
n-k\right)  z\right)  ^{n-k-1}=\left(  x+y\right)  \left(  x+y-nz\right)
^{n-1}.
$$
This proves Theorem 2. $\square$

Finally, we can get Theorem 1:

*First proof of Theorem 1.* Theorem 2 (applied to $n-2$ instead of $n$) shows
that in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[  x,y,z\right]  $, we have
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\dbinom{n-2}{k}xy\left(  x-kz\right)  ^{k-1}\left(
y-\left(  \left(  n-2\right)  -k\right)  z\right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)
-k-1}\\
& =\left(  x+y\right)  \left(  x+y-\left(  n-2\right)  z\right)  ^{n-3}.
\end{align*}
Substituting $1$, $1$ and $-1$ for $x$, $y$ and $z$ in this equality (and
making the obvious simplifications), we find
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\dbinom{n-2}{k}\left(  1+k\right)  ^{k-1}\left(  1+\left(
\left(  n-2\right)  -k\right)  \right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  -k-1}\\
& =2\left(  2+\left(  n-2\right)  \right)  ^{n-3}=2n^{n-3}.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
2n^{n-3}  & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}\dbinom{n-2}{k}\left(  1+k\right)  ^{k-1}\left(
1+\left(  \left(  n-2\right)  -k\right)  \right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)
-k-1}\\
& =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-2}{i-1}\left(  1+\left(  i-1\right)  \right)
^{\left(  i-1\right)  -1}\left(  1+\left(  \left(  n-2\right)  -\left(
i-1\right)  \right)  \right)  ^{\left(  n-2\right)  -\left(  i-1\right)  -1}
\end{align*}
(here, we have substituted $i-1$ for $k$ in the sum). After some trivial
simplifications, this becomes
$$
2n^{n-3}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-2}{i-1}i^{i-2}\left(  n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}.
$$
Dividing this equality by $2$, we obtain the claim of Theorem 1. $\square$

### Second proof: Cayley's formula and the symmetry of trees

Let me say right away that the above first proof of Theorem 1 is my favorite,
since it shows various rather general combinatorial identities in cascade. In
contrast, the following second proof is cute and memorable.

A *tree* shall here mean a simple undirected graph (i.e., a pair $\left(
V,E\right)  $ in which $V$ is a finite set and $E$ is a set of $2$-element
subsets of $V$) that is connected and has no cycles. Of course, various other
equivalent characterizations of trees exist. If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then an
*$n$-tree* means a tree whose vertex set is $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $.
Notice that there exist no $0$-trees, since a graph with no vertices is not
connected. If $G=\left(  V,E\right)  $ is a simple undirected graph, then the
edge set $E$ is denoted by $\operatorname*{E}\left(  G\right)  $.

The following theorem is one of the famous results of 19th century
combinatorics -- the [Cayley
formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%5C27s_formula) (actually
discovered by Borchardt in 1860):

> **Theorem 5.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then, the number of all
>   $n$-trees is $n^{n-2}$.

The similarity of the $n^{n-2}$ term here with the powers in Theorem 1
suggests a relation, and such indeed exists. First, let me derive a corollary
of Theorem 5:

> **Corollary 6.** Let $n\geq2$ be an integer. Let $f$ be a $2$-element subset
>   of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. Then, the number of all $n$-trees $T$
>   such that $f\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ is $2n^{n-3}$.

*Proof of Corollary 6.* It is well-known that the number of edges in a tree is
always its number of vertices minus $1$. Thus, a tree with $n$ vertices must
have exactly $n-1$ edges. In other words, any $n$-tree must have exactly $n-1$ edges.

Let $F$ be the set of all $2$-element subsets of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,n\right\}  $. Then, for each $n$-tree $T$, we have $\operatorname*{E}\left(
T\right)  \subseteq F$ (that is, the edges of $T$ are elements of $F$). Also,
$f$ is a $2$-element subset of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ and thus
belongs to $F$. Also, clearly, $\left\vert F\right\vert =\dbinom{n}{2}
=\dfrac{n\left(  n-1\right)  }{2}$.

Now, we claim that any $e\in F$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }\left\{
1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  \nonumber\\
\tag{3}
=\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }
e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  .
\label{pf.c6.1}
\end{align}

[*Proof of \eqref{pf.c6.1}:* Let $e\in F$. Thus, $e$ is a $2$-element subset
of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. In other words, $e=\left\{  x,y\right\}
$ for two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $.
Consider these $x$ and $y$.

The elements $x$ and $y$ of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ are distinct.
Thus, there exists some permutation $\sigma$ of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,n\right\}  $ such that $\sigma\left(  1\right)  =x$ and $\sigma\left(
2\right)  =y$. (For example, one can find such a permutation $\sigma$ by
setting its first two values $\sigma\left(  1\right)  $ and $\sigma\left(
2\right)  $ to be $x$ and $y$, and setting all its remaining $n-2$ values to
be the remaining $n-2$ elements of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ in any
order.) Consider such a $\sigma$.

Recall that any permutation $\omega$ of $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ also
induces a permutation of the set $F$ of all $2$-element subsets of $\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ (namely, it sends each $g\in F$ to $\omega\left( g \right)  =\left\{  \omega\left(  u\right)  \ \mid\ u\in g \right\}  $). In
particular, $\sigma$ induces a permutation of the set $F$. This permutation
satisfies $\sigma\left(  \left\{  1,2\right\}  \right)  =\left\{
\underbrace{\sigma\left(  1\right)  }_{=x},\underbrace{\sigma\left(  2\right)
}_{=y}\right\}  =\left\{  x,y\right\}  =e$.

If $T$ is an $n$-tree, and if $\omega$ is a permutation of $\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $, then $\omega\left(  T\right)  $ shall denote the
$n$-tree whose edges are the images of the edges of $T$ under $\omega$ (that
is, $\operatorname*{E}\left(  \omega\left(  T\right)  \right)  =\left\{
\omega\left(  e\right)  \ \mid\ e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\right\}  $). It is easy to see that this $\omega\left(  T\right)  $ is indeed
an $n$-tree (indeed, it is just the $n$-tree $T$ with its vertices relabelled
by the map $\omega$). Hence, the map
$$
\left\{  n\text{-trees}\right\}  \rightarrow\left\{  n\text{-trees}\right\}
,\ T\mapsto\sigma\left(  T\right)
$$
is well-defined. Moreover, this map is a bijection (indeed, the map $\left\{
n\text{-trees}\right\}  \rightarrow\left\{  n\text{-trees}\right\}
,\ T\mapsto\sigma^{-1}\left(  T\right)  $ is easily seen to be inverse to it).
This bijection restricts to a bijection
\begin{align*}
\left\{  n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }\left\{  1,2\right\}
\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right\}    & \rightarrow\left\{
n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\right\}  ,\\
T  & \mapsto\sigma\left(  T\right)
\end{align*}
(since $\sigma\left(  \left\{  1,2\right\}  \right)  =e$). Hence, the sets
$\left\{  n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }\left\{  1,2\right\}
\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right\}  $ and $\left\{  n\text{-trees
}T\text{ such that }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right\}  $ are in
bijection. Thus, these two sets have the same size. In other words,
\eqref{pf.c6.1} holds.]

Now,
\begin{align*}
& \left(  \text{the number of all pairs }\left(  T,e\right)  \text{ where
}T\text{ is an }n\text{-tree and }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{T\text{ is an }n\text{-tree}}\underbrace{\left(  \text{the number of
all }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  }_{\substack{=\left\vert
\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right\vert =\left(  \text{the number of
all edges of }T\right)  =n-1\\\text{(since any }n\text{-tree must have exactly
}n-1\text{ edges)}}}\\
& =\sum\limits_{T\text{ is an }n\text{-tree}}\left(  n-1\right)  =\left(  n-1\right)
\cdot\underbrace{\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees}\right)
}_{\substack{=n^{n-2}\\\text{(by Theorem 5)}}}\\
& =\left(  n-1\right)  \cdot n^{n-2}.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
& \left(  n-1\right)  \cdot n^{n-2}\\
& =\left(  \text{the number of all pairs }\left(  T,e\right)  \text{ where
}T\text{ is an }n\text{-tree and }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{e\in F}\underbrace{\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees
}T\text{ such that }e\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)
}_{\substack{=\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such
that }\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)
\\\text{(by \eqref{pf.c6.1})}}}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{since }\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\subseteq F\text{ for each }n\text{-tree }T\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{e\in F}\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such
that }\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  \\
& =\underbrace{\left\vert F\right\vert }_{=\dfrac{n\left(  n-1\right)  }{2}
} \cdot \underbrace{\left(  \text{the number
of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in
\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  }_{\substack{=\left(  \text{the
number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }f\in\operatorname*{E}\left(
T\right)  \right)  \\\text{(by \eqref{pf.c6.1}, applied to }e=f\text{)}}}\\
& =\dfrac{n\left(  n-1\right)  }{2}\cdot\left(  \text{the number of all
}n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }f\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)
\right)  .
\end{align*}
Solving this equality for $\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees
}T\text{ such that }f\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)  $, we
obtain
\begin{align*}
\left(  \text{the number of all }n\text{-trees }T\text{ such that }
f\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  \right)    & =\left(  n-1\right)  \cdot
n^{n-2}/\dfrac{n\left(  n-1\right)  }{2}\\
& =2n^{n-3}.
\end{align*}
This proves Corollary 6. $\square$

Here is another trivial corollary of Theorem 5:

> **Corollary 7.** Let $S$ be a finite nonempty set. Then, the number of all
>   trees with vertex set $S$ is $\left\vert S\right\vert ^{\left\vert
> S\right\vert -2}$.

*Proof of Corollary 7.* Let $n=\left\vert S\right\vert $. Then, there exists a
bijection $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  \rightarrow S$. We can use this
bijection to transform any $n$-tree into a tree with vertex set $S$ (by
relabelling its vertices) and vice versa. Hence, the number of all trees with
vertex set $S$ equals the number of all $n$-trees. But the latter number is
$n^{n-2}$ (by Theorem 5). Hence, the former number is also $n^{n-2}$. In other
words, the number of all trees with vertex set $S$ is $n^{n-2}=\left\vert
S\right\vert ^{\left\vert S\right\vert -2}$ (since $n=\left\vert S\right\vert
$). Corollary 7 is proven. $\square$

Now, we can finally reprove Theorem 1:

*Second proof of Theorem 1.* Corollary 6 (applied to $f=\left\{  1,2\right\}
$) shows that the number of all $n$-trees $T$ satisfying $\left\{
1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ is $2n^{n-3}$.

Now, let me show a different way to compute this number.

Indeed, if we remove the edge $\left\{  1,2\right\}  $ from an $n$-tree $T$
satisfying $\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $,
then the remaining graph splits into two connected components, one of which
contains the vertex $1$ while the other contains the vertex $2$. Both
connected components are trees; we denote them by $A_{T}$ and $B_{T}$,
respectively (so that $1$ is a vertex of $A_{T}$ and $2$ is a vertex of
$B_{T}$). Let $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ be the vertex set of the tree $A_{T}$, and let
$\mathcal{B}_{T}$ be the vertex set of the tree $B_{T}$. Then, $\mathcal{A}
_{T}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{T}$ are two disjoint subsets of $\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ whose union is $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $;
thus, $\mathcal{B}_{T}=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  \setminus\mathcal{A}
_{T}$. Note that $1\in\mathcal{A}_{T}$ (since $1$ is a vertex of $A_{T}$) and
$2\in\mathcal{B}_{T}$ (since $2$ is a vertex of $B_{T}$), thus $2\in
\mathcal{B}_{T}=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  \setminus\mathcal{A}_{T}$, thus
$2\notin\mathcal{A}_{T}$.

Obviously, an $n$-tree $T$ satisfying $\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in
\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ is uniquely determined by the two trees
$A_{T}$ and $B_{T}$. Thus, any $n$-tree $T$ satisfying $\left\{  1,2\right\}
\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ can be constructed by the following procedure:

1. First, we decide how many elements the set $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ will have
   (i.e., how many vertices $A_{T}$ will have). The number of elements of
   $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ has to be an integer from $1$ to $n-1$ (in fact, it cannot
   be $0$ (since we must have $1\in\mathcal{A}_{T}$); but it cannot be $n$ either
   (since we must have $2\notin\mathcal{A}_{T}$)). We choose one such integer,
   and denote it by $i$. We thus want the set $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ to have $i$ elements.
2. Then, we choose the set $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ itself (i.e., we decide which
   vertices $A_{T}$ will have). We already know that this set will have $i$
   elements, and we know that $1$ will be one of them (since $1\in\mathcal{A}
   _{T}$) but $2$ will be not (since $2\notin\mathcal{A}_{T}$); thus, we are left
   to choose the remaining $i-1$ elements of $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ freely among the
   $n-2$ numbers $3,4,\ldots,n$. There are $\dbinom{n-2}{i-1}$ ways to make this choice.
3. Having chosen the set $\mathcal{A}_{T}$, we immediately know the set
   $\mathcal{B}_{T}$: namely, $\mathcal{B}_{T}=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}
   \setminus\mathcal{A}_{T}$ (there are no choices to make here). Notice that
   $\left\vert \mathcal{A}_{T}\right\vert =i$ (since the set $\mathcal{A}_{T}$
   has $i$ elements), and from $\mathcal{B}_{T}=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}
   \setminus\mathcal{A}_{T}$ we obtain $\left\vert \mathcal{B}_{T}\right\vert
   =\left\vert \left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  \setminus\mathcal{A}_{T}\right\vert
   =\underbrace{\left\vert \left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  \right\vert }
   _{=n}-\underbrace{\left\vert \mathcal{A}_{T}\right\vert }_{=i}=n-i$. Note that
   both sets $\mathcal{A}_{T}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{T}$ are nonempty (since
   $1\in\mathcal{A}_{T}$ but $2\in\mathcal{B}_{T}$ (since $2\notin\mathcal{A}
   _{T}$)).
4. Now, we choose the tree $A_{T}$. This tree has to be a tree with vertex set
   $\mathcal{A}_{T}$; the number of all such trees is $\left\vert \mathcal{A}
   _{T}\right\vert ^{\left\vert \mathcal{A}_{T}\right\vert -2}$ (by Corollary 7,
   applied to $S=\mathcal{A}_{T}$). In other words, the number of all such trees
   is $i^{i-2}$ (since $\left\vert \mathcal{A}_{T}\right\vert =i$). Thus, there
   are $i^{i-2}$ ways to choose $A_{T}$.
5. Now, we choose the tree $B_{T}$. This tree has to be a tree with vertex set
   $\mathcal{B}_{T}$; the number of all such trees is $\left\vert \mathcal{B}
   _{T}\right\vert ^{\left\vert \mathcal{B}_{T}\right\vert -2}$ (by Corollary 7,
   applied to $S=\mathcal{B}_{T}$). In other words, the number of all such trees
   is $\left(  n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}$ (since $\left\vert \mathcal{B}
   _{T}\right\vert =n-i$). Thus, there are $\left(  n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}$ ways to
   choose $B_{T}$.
6. Finally, we assemble the $n$-tree $T$ from $A_{T}$ and $B_{T}$ by adding
   the edge $\left\{  1,2\right\}  $.

This procedure clearly yields any $n$-tree $T$ satisfying $\left\{
1,2\right\}  \in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ in a unique way. Thus,
the number of all $n$-trees $T$ satisfying $\left\{  1,2\right\}
\in\operatorname*{E}\left(  T\right)  $ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-2}
{i-1}i^{i-2}\left(  n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}$ (because this is how many ways we
have to make choices in the above procedure). Comparing this with the fact
that this number is $2n^{n-3}$ (as shown above), we conclude that
$$
2n^{n-3}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-2}{i-1}i^{i-2}\left(  n-i\right)  ^{n-i-2}.
$$
Dividing this equality by $2$, we obtain the claim of Theorem 1. $\square$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! The combinatorial proof is very nice, and I have some hope that Abel's identity will solve my bigger question (I added a link in the original post), once I have time to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

In my (first research) paper, [A note on evaluation of Abel's sums](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316579900475/1-s2.0-0097316579900475-main.pdf?_tid=eebe5070-5f49-11e7-b7b0-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1499015860_bee8903d8ee4407bd73d68e296eee4a9), (that appeared second, in 1979) I described another way to evaluate Abel's sum of the form $$A_n(x,y;p,q)=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n} \choose {k}}(k+x)^{k+p}(n-k+y)^{n-k+q},$$ via (simpler) auxiliary sums defined by $$F_n(x,y;p,q)=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n} \choose {k}}(-1)^k (k+x)^{p}(n-k+y)^{q}.$$ The $F_n$ functions have simple evaluations in terms of difference operators. I was inspired by Riordan's book Combinatorial Identities and later corresponded with Riordan, and met him in 78.